# no interaction with SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vivagraphjs

im using vivagraph to embed a svg into a div (as a background) it works fine, but vivagraph offers interaction (scroll zoom) is there anyway to remove that kind of interaction with the svg?

I tried to tie up an eventlistner to the svg and disable it through there.

Is there not an easy way to just say "dont interact with svg just scroll down"?

Thanks

Comment: can you show current code or create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create renderer set `interactive: false` that will prevent vivagraph from handling all user input:

```
var renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
    graphics: graphics,
    interactive: false,
    container: document.getElementById('graph-container')
});
```

If you want to have fine-grained control over what to allow VivaGraph, starting from version `0.7.7` you can set `interactive` value to be a string value, which lists enabled features. See more documentation and interactive examples here: [no interaction](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/tree/master/demos/other/input-override#no-interaction).

Comment: Very cool Anvaka! And thanks for a goddamn cool lib! Have a nice day!